# java and maven instalation in windows 10 variables

Tags: java, maven

after searching here and few sites i didnt get clear answer of instalation of maven 3.60 and installation of java (JDK and JRE) as variables.

wha i did till now about the maven is under

```
Environment Variable and than system variables and add there under PATH the c:\\apache-maven-3.6.0\bin
```

according to [here](https://maven.apache.org/install.html)
so about the maven, is these is all the places i should add?
what about M2_HOME and MAVEN_HOME

about the JAVA i just saw the adding to

```
 Environment Variable -->user variables->JAVA_HOME->Edit -> C:\jdk 11.0.2
```

these is all the places and all the folders i should add? and all the variables? i didnt find a clear answer yet

i want to work with my eclipse with java and to use the MAVEN with command line and his functions in eclipse and else.

Comment: What do you want to do? I mean what's the final purpose of adding variables, doesn't something work?

Comment: good point - added to main question too.
want to work with my eclipse with java and to use the MAVEN with command line and his functions in eclipse and else.
i want also to write it to myself so it will be availabe to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most minimalistic way to make maven available in command line:

1. Add maven `bin` folder to `PATH` variable
2. Ensure `JAVA_HOME` is set up.

Details:

- `PATH` is an environment variable, specifying a set of directories
  where executable programs are located. Specifically, if you want
  maven to be available for all users set it under `System variables`,
  and if you want it to be available only for specific user - under
  `User variables`.
- `MAVEN_OPTS` environment variable contains parameters used to start up the JVM running Maven and can be used to supply additional options. E.g. JVM memory settings could be defined with the value `-Xms256m -Xmx512m`.
- `MAVEN_HOME` is used for maven 1 and `M2_HOME` is used to locate maven 2. Having the two different `_HOME` variables means it is possible to run both on the same machine.
- Starting from [Maven 3.5](https://maven.apache.org/docs/3.5.0/release-notes.html) the usage of `M2_HOME` has been removed
  and is not supported any more.
- For maven version 2 and up to 3.5, this is how you should set `M2` and `M2_HOME` in combination with `PATH`, for example:

```
M2_HOME=C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.6.0
M2=%M2_HOME%\bin
PATH=%M2%;%PATH%
```

Comment: @timothy I've updated the unswer. As described in `Details` secion about `PATH` variable: if you want to make the programm available for all users set its path under `System variables`, and if you want it to be available only for specific user - under `User variables`.

Comment: so according to version 3.6 (current)
i need for all user under `System variables`:
`Environment Variable -->system variables->Path->Edit-> c:\apache-maven-3.6.0\bin` and JAVA_HOME c:\jdk 11.0.2 , correct?
about the MAVEN_OPTS, where to set it and how?
also i understand that no need for maven 1 and maven 2 anymore

Comment: @timothy Personally, I would recommend setting all this variables as `User variables`. For example, do the following: 1) open up the system properties (WinKey + Pause); 2) go to `Advanced` > `Environment Variables` 3) add or select the `PATH` variable in the `User variables`; 4) paste maven `bin` path, e.g. `C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.6.0\bin`. The same steps can be used to set `JAVA_HOME` to the location of your `JDK`, e.g. `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_202`. Also the same applies for `MAVEN_OPTS`.

Comment: @Zgurskyi, in the answer above should the last line not be PATH = %M2%;%PATH%

Comment: @Zgurskyi beside of security, what the reason to add it just for one user?
also these is all i need to add in order to work with the maven + java? PATH of maven and JAVA_HOME?

Comment: @timothy Actually, security is the major reason. But if it's not your concern - then you can define all variables as `System` wide - so maven will be available to all users. Regarding second part - yes it should be enough (putting maven `bin` to `PATH` and defining `JAVA_HOME`). Doesn't it work for you?

Comment: and i guess no need to old version if i work with the 3.60, so only JAVA_HOME and PATH to bin

Comment: Yes. For latest version - other vars can be just ignored. I wouldn't mentioned other variables, if you didn't asked about them in the question :)

Comment: @Zgurskyi i wanted to make order in my files ones :) thank you for the clarify on these

Comment: Setting of `M2` nor `M2_HOME` is needed and had never been needed.